# Replacing a substring inside a string in powershell script

Tags: string, powershell

I have long text files, containing markup for another software. The form of the text is this:

```
*INIT=D:\ws\**randomnonesense*
 ROW=THISISROW,D:\ws\morestuff
 PALVELU=200,WSTIME70.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=201,WSLDIR70.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=202,WSLDIX70.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=204,WSEXCE32.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=205,WMON.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=206,WSWORD32.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=207,WSLEPT32.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=208,WSCONV70.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=209,WSFTPC70.DLL,N,A
 KUVAUS=\\192.168.169.17\adwise$\applic\LIKSA_TURE.A70,D:\ws\%aspno%\%username%
 MDBS-KANTA=LIKSAV,%aspno%LIK.DB,5,RTTL,ANSI,111.111.111.11MDBS- 
 KANTA=LANKA,%aspno%LAN.DB,5,RTTL,ANSI,1000.000.111.11
```

I am writing a script, that needs to replace all of those rows that start with the word PALVELU. The amount of other stuff before and after those rows can be any. Also number of those PALVELU-rows or their lenght is not the same in every file. Still I would need to replace all of those rows in every file with another set of rows. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method: 
**Replace(oldStr, newStr)** 
eg: 
Write-Host "replacing a text in string" 
$test=" old text to be replaced" 
Write-Host "going to replace old" 
$test.Replace("old","New") 
Write-Host "Text is replaced"

Hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[regex]::split` to split content of your file by lines, after you have all line you can check if each line contain the word **PALVELU** using `-like` operator.

I use `\n` in the regex pattern to split your content on every start of a newline

```
$rows = [regex]::split("*INIT=D:\ws\**randomnonesense*
 ROW=THISISROW,D:\ws\morestuff
 PALVELU=200,WSTIME70.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=201,WSLDIR70.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=202,WSLDIX70.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=204,WSEXCE32.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=205,WMON.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=206,WSWORD32.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=207,WSLEPT32.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=208,WSCONV70.DLL,N,A
 PALVELU=209,WSFTPC70.DLL,N,A
 KUVAUS=\\192.168.169.17\adwise$\applic\LIKSA_TURE.A70,D:\ws\%aspno%\%username%
 MDBS-KANTA=LIKSAV,%aspno%LIK.DB,5,RTTL,ANSI,111.111.111.11MDBS-
 KANTA=LANKA,%aspno%LAN.DB,5,RTTL,ANSI,1000.000.111.11", "(.*)\n")

$output = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

foreach($row in $rows) {
    if($row -like '*PALVELU*') {
        $output.Add($row.Replace("PALVELU", "TEST")) | Out-Null
    } else {
        $output.Add($row) | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to replace each `PALVELU` row with a new row, you may do the following:

```
# Assumes your file is a.txt
$ReplaceThis = '^PALVELU.*$'
$ReplaceWith = '<new row>'
$(switch -regex -file a.txt {
    $ReplaceThis { $_ -replace $ReplaceThis,$ReplaceWith }
    Default { $_ }
}) | Set-Content a.txt
```

The code above will result in X number of `PALVELU` rows being replaced with X number of `<new row>`.

---

If the goal is to replace consecutive `PALVELU` rows with a single `<new row>` string in files that only contain one set of consecutive `PALVELU` rows, you may do the following:

```
$ReplaceThis = '(?sm)^PALVELU.*(?-s)^PALVELU.*$'
$ReplaceWith = '<new row>'
(Get-Content a.txt -Raw) -replace $ReplaceThis,$ReplaceWith |
    Set-Content a.txt
```

---

If the goal is to replace all `PALVELU` rows with a single `<new row>` string at the location of the first `PALVELU` row and the rows could be anywhere in the file, you may do the following:

```
$ReplaceThis = '^PALVELU.*$'
$ReplaceWith = '<new row>'
$firstMatch = $false
$(switch -regex -file a.txt {
    $ReplaceThis {
        if ($firstMatch) { 
            $_ -replace $ReplaceThis
        }
        else {
            $_ -replace $ReplaceThis,$ReplaceWith
            $firstMatch = $true
        }
    }
    default { $_ }
}) -ne '' | Set-Content a.txt
```